# After theme installation on Magento 1.9, it throws Exception Error

Tags: magento-1.9

Just uploaded a new theme and now get the error

Here is the log:

```
Trace:
#0 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Helper/Data.php(617): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Helper/Data.php(634): Magentothem_Revslider_Helper_Data->getAllCaptionInSlide()
#12 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Block/Revslider.php(26): Magentothem_Revslider_Helper_Data->initCss()
#13 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Magentothem_Revslider_Block_Revslider->_toHtml()
#14 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('ma_banner', true)
#18 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_optician/ma_optician4/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(47): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('ma_banner')
#19 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/xxxxxx/...')
#20 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ma_opt...')
#21 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'ma_optician4_ho...')
#27 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'ma_optician4_ho...')
#28 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#29 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#30 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}
```

I did this but it didn't resolve the issue.

```
Navigate to the "errors" folder.

Change local.xml.sample to local.xml

You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.

Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and look for:

protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'null',
Change it to:

protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
Save it.
Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.
```

Any more pointers on what's wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess theme table are missing in database. Could you please check `install.sql` data are updated in database.

Module path: `/home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Magentothem/Revslider`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where exactly can I verify that?

Comment: Verify the "/home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Magentothem/Revslider/sql/install.sql" sql data are found in your database.